# Excel: Add month to previous date incrementally, giving same date for all months

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to sequential dates over a period of months based on the given input date.

[image]

Current excel formula: `=--(MONTH(B2+32) & "/" & DAY(B$2) & "/" & YEAR(B2+32))`

Input date format: `DD-MM-YYYY`

Version: Microsoft office Home and Student 2019

Can someone please provide the excel formula for this?

Comment: There are issues with all of the solutions if the initial date is on the 28th or later. eg initial date `30-Sep-2022`. Do you want subsequent dates to be on the 30th?  or on the last day of the month? What about `30-Jan-2022`.  If your dates will always be prior to the 28th, then there should not be an issue, but if not, think carefully about what you want.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Consider this every month installment date. For the 28th or later dates, it should be the same day or best possible max day of next month.

Comment: Then I suggest to use an `IF` to determine whether to use an `EDATE` function or, possibly the `EOMONTH` function

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Sounds good! Can you provide it as answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [EDATE function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/edate-function-3c920eb2-6e66-44e7-a1f5-753ae47ee4f5):

> Returns the serial number that represents the date that is the indicated number of months before or after a specified date (the start_date). Use EDATE to calculate maturity dates or due dates that fall on the same day of the month as the date of issue.

```
=EDATE(B2,1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

With the start date in `A1`
Type this in A2:
`=DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+1,DAY(A1))`
(fill down)

*Expected to work in all Excel, Libreoffice and OpenOffice versions.*

Comment: Note; the result "here" will be a valid date; therefore you can use the normal cell formatting to DISPLAY it in any valid date format - i.e. no need to build it up with concatenated strings.